# to calculate Time difference

Tags: php, mysqli

I want is to calculate the time difference from to times intime and outtime. I did the below code and at the end face an error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\testsite\time_test.php on line 105

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testsite") OR die("Could not connect: ".mysqli_error());
    
if (isset($_POST['isubmit'])) {
    // Check the cookie exits or not
    if (isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
        $_COOKIE['uid'];
    }

    $uid = $_COOKIE['uid'];

    echo "Hello user: ".$uid;

    $isql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `time`(`uid`, `intime`, `date`) VALUES ('$uid',CURTIME(),CURDATE())");
    $lid = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    echo $lid;
}
if (isset($_POST['osubmit'])) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
        $_COOKIE['uid'];
    }

    $uid = $_COOKIE['uid'];
    $ssql= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `intime`, `outtime`, `date` FROM `time` WHERE `uid`=".$uid);
    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ssql)) {
        $intime = $row['intime'];
        $outtime= $row['outtime'];  
        $date   = $row['date'];
        
        if(!empty($date)){
            $tmp = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT CURTIME()");
            $lid = mysqli_insert_id($con);
                    
            $temp= strtotime($outtime) - strtotime($intime);
                    
            echo $temp;
            //below line is line number 105
            $usql= "UPDATE `time` SET `outtime`= $tmp,`diff`= '$temp' WHERE `id`=".$lid." AND `uid`=".$uid;
            $run = mysqli_query($con, $usql);
            if (!$run) {
                die("Update database query error: ". mysqli_error());
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$tmp = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT CURTIME()");` might be a bit over kill don't you think ? Unless your mysql server is different from your apache server and runs under another GMT

Comment: I am always doing first on local drive than after upload it and change the necessary things which i point out in diary. Through this I get the time from my computer and it's good at this time. I just want to get rid from the error...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `$tmp` var is a query, not a result of the query. You have to fetch the result first. That is why you get this error. But you could get the time with PHP, without having to do a query :

```
$tmp = date('H:i:s');
```

Also, your `$temp` variable will result as an integer. Use the `date` function to format it :

```
$temp = date('H:i:s', strtotime($outtime) - strtotime($intime));
```

Also be aware that you are subject to SQL injections : your `$uid` is a cookie that is not safe. You might want to cast it as an integer :

```
$uid = (int)$_COOKIE['uid'];
```

Or you can do it better and use [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: I replace the $tmp to $otime in the arithmatic operation but when I did this I face an same error again with one warning

Comment: Dump your variables and see what you got before making your `$usql`

Comment: okay I used int and after that as I am taking the curtime() for both time intime and outtime than in $temp i get this type of value 1417643818. however i convert it in to h.m.s but can't see any change

Comment: Yeah not when I enter the intime 15.10.00 and outtime is 15.11.00 than I see the difference is 09:49:48 rather than 00.01.00 anyway thanks and what you think is there any problem in my update query?

Comment: I don't understand... Do you still have a problem ? It works for me : http://codepad.org/1j0mKzq3 `var_dump` your variables and your query.